Унификация выбора типа на этапе исполнения (run-time)
Мне нужно, чтобы конкретный тип определялся на этапе исполнения. Типов фиксированное количество, но много. Если точно, то 256. Я сделал мэйкер. Но выглядит это жутко.
static TBase* NewObj(unsigned char num)
{
    switch (num)
    {
    case 0: return new TDerived<0>;
    case 1: return new TDerived<1>;
    case 2: return new TDerived<2>;
    case 3: return new TDerived<3>;
    case 4: return new TDerived<4>;
    case 5: return new TDerived<5>;
    case 6: return new TDerived<6>;
    case 7: return new TDerived<7>;
    case 8: return new TDerived<8>;
    case 9: return new TDerived<9>;
    case 10: return new TDerived<10>;
    case 11: return new TDerived<11>;
    case 12: return new TDerived<12>;
    case 13: return new TDerived<13>;
    case 14: return new TDerived<14>;
    case 15: return new TDerived<15>;
    // ...
    // ...
    default: return nullptr;
    }
}

Можно это сделать без 256 case'ов? Или это нормально? Или я опять туплю?

А так ли уж нужен именно шаблон?... А не обычный класс, типа, return new TDerived(14)?

@Harry нужен для того, чтобы я мог напрямую обращаться к полям объекта типа TDerived, когда NUM мне известен на этапе компиляции, и мог обращаться к ним через виртуальные методы TBase, когда NUM известен только на этапе исполнения. TBase - это интерфейс. А TDerived - обёртка над статическим массивом.

И да, конечно, я знаю, можно всё это через vector. Но мне нужно (хочется) несколько шаблонных методов, аргументы которых зависят от NUM, но run-time проверки не нужны (не хочу).

Так-то оно вроде получается, как я и хочу. Но как-то дико выглядят эти case, case, case....

static TBase* NewObj(unsigned char num) { return return new TDerived<num>; }

@Faraday error: 'num' is not a constant expression

То есть вам одна лишняя проверка дороже, чем все равно проверка + компиляция 256 разных классов?

Не просто одна проверка, а одно разыменование. А компиляция кода под 256 реализаций класса - это не дорого (они лёгкие будут, ну по крайней мере пока))). К тому же методы, которые можно использовать, когда знаешь NUM, лучше инлайнятся (по крайней мере пока инлайнятся). А это уже 2 разыменования.

Вместо case можно запихнуть указатели на функции в таблицу:
template<unsigned char num>
auto
MakeObj()
{ 
    return ::std::unique_ptr<TBase>{new TDerived<num>{}};
}

template<unsigned char... num_pack>
constexpr auto
MakeLut(::std::integer_sequence<unsigned char, num_pack...>)
{
    return ::std::array{&MakeObj<num_pack>...};
}

constexpr auto lut{MakeLut(::std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned char, 255>())};

auto NewObj(unsigned char num)
{
    return (*lut[num])();
}


Да, спасибо. Кажись, то, что искал integer_sequence - оно самое.

*make_integer_sequence
